# Network not working after changing MAC

Tags: networking, mac-address

I changed MAC address of my virtual computer with OS `Ubuntu`. (`ifconfig enp0s3 hw ether 12:23:34:45:56:67`) After that I was no more able to communicate with any network devices.

Is there anything I should do after changing MAC to make network work again ? Or are there any rules for editing MAC address ?

EDIT : I use `VirtualBox`

Comment: Your virtual machine uses virtual hardware. You would have to change the host MAC address. Changing MAC addresses is generally not a good idea anyway. They are vendor (manufacturer) specific

Comment: Which virtual software are you using?

Comment: Some hypervisors will restrict by default the MAC address that can be used by the VM (to the one that was given to it initially). So (again, harrymc asked it) what's your hypervisor? Also your tag should probably be `mac-address` rather than `mac`.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: The interesting question here is **why** you think you need to change the MAC address of a simulated network card on a VM? What benefit should it give you? Could you solve your problem (whatever it is) by configuring VirtualBox to already start the VM with a different MAC?

Comment: I indeed could do that. It is working now. Thank for your answer. You can create an "official" answer co I can mark it useful.

Comment: You can also answer your own question, and include details **how** you configured VirtualBox with a particular MAC address, so the next person with a similar problem can benefit from this. But I am still curios **why** you need to change a MAC address on simulated hardware, that will probably only be visible in network traffic between the VM and the host? I don't see any benefit in doing that, unless you have an interesting situation you didn't tell us about.